# Group objects by specific column in admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class Attack(models.Model):
    action_id = models.IntegerField()
    village_id = models.IntegerField()
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    enemy_village_id = models.IntegerField()
    attack_start = models.DateTimeField()
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

That is what i see in change_list
[image]
This is data:
[image]
And this is how i want to see in admin change list:
[image]

And when i click on some action id i want to see view like in first screen but only for this id.
I have no idea how to do it... I tried add custom view but it is not that simply so maybe someone know solution for my problem.

Comment: Not quite sure if group by is something that you want to do in the admin area, but if it is, the right way to do it is by modifying the query set in get_queryset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuret it out. I added one model:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    some_field = models.IntegerField()
```

I edited my Attack model:

```
class Attack(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
```

And i used inline display:

```
class AttackInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Attack
  extra = 1

class ActionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = ( AttackInline, )

admin.site.register(Action, ActionAdmin)
```

But anyway i will write custom view.